# Ruby TCP server with OpenSSL and Letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'd like to setup a minimal Ruby TCP server with SSL layer using certificate generated from Letsencrypt.

I install packages (system is Ubuntu 18, 64 bit):

```
    sudo apt install ruby certbot
```

I generate the cert like this:

```
    certonly -d example.com
```

Then run the following code:

```
    require "socket"
    require "openssl"
    require "base64"

    port = 443
    cert_path = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
    key_path = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
    chain_path = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem"

    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( File.read( cert_path ))
    context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new( File.read( key_path ))
    context.extra_chain_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new( File.read( chain_path ))
    tcp_server = TCPServer.new( port )
    ssl_server = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new( tcp_server, context )

    loop {

        client = ssl_server.accept

        data = client.gets
        response = "I got #{data.dump}"

        puts response
        client.puts response
        client.close

    }
```

Then send a POST request using curl like this:

```
    curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
5: from api.rb:35:in `<main>'
4: from api.rb:35:in `loop'
3: from api.rb:37:in `block in <main>'
2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/openssl-2.1.2/lib/openssl/ssl.rb:483:in `accept'
1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/openssl-2.1.2/lib/openssl/ssl.rb:483:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/openssl-2.1.2/lib/openssl/ssl.rb:483:in `initialize': undefined method `each' for #<OpenSSL::X509::Certificate:0x0000556df03c22c0> (NoMethodError)
```

Could you guys kindly help me track down the problem? I've been struggling with this for some time now. The official example does not work either which is here:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-SSL+and+TLS+Connections

I've read in a SO thread that for Letsencrpyt certs I should include the .extra_chain_cert property. Still the issue is the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extra_chain_cert` property is supposed to be an array according to its [documentation](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html), but you are just setting it to be a single certificate.  The `openssl` gem is crashing because it expected that property to be an array and called the `each` method on it to iterate over the elements of the array.

You can try putting your certificate into a one-element array by enclosing it in square brackets (`[` and `]`).

```
context.extra_chain_cert = [OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(chain_path))]
```

I just tested it here using my own Lets Encrypt certificate and it worked for me. I used port 444, and when I pointed a browser to https://example.com:444 the Ruby program said:

```
I got "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

Comment: Note that in general, any number of intermediate certificates might be required to form a full chain of trust from your certificate back to a trusted root.  My answer only works if there is just one certificate, so it might need to be fixed in the future if Lets Encrypt starts using a longer chain.